# Node-red print global var in message nodes

Tags: node-red

I am quite new to node-red and there is something that bother me that I can't make it work.
I am currently making a chat-bot on facebook messenger, and I want to print a global variable but I can't seem to understand the syntax to print it.
Here is how I declare my variable : `msg.payload = global.get("glob");`. I know the variable isn't empty because when I print it with `node.error(global.get("glob");` it displays the string.
But then I try to print it on a message node with `{msg.payload}` (and multiples other tries) but it either prints nothing or `undefined`.
What is the correct syntax to print those variables?

This is my message node : 
[image]

And this is the result : [image]

Comment: What node are you trying to use `var : {msg.payload}` as the value of the Title property? How that gets interpreted will be up to that node's implementation. So it is not possible to answer this question without more information.

Answer (score 2):

use `context.global.yourvariable` to declare global variables, for example:

```
context.global.ss = msg.payload;
```

now `context.global.ss` can be accessed by any node in the flow.

Hope this helps!